# Dockerfile RUN Shellscript erro ao executar if

Tags: docker

Estou com um problema ao fazer um build no dockerfile onde preciso executar um ShellScript para que insira palavra master dentro dele e nele contem apenas a verificação de uma pasta se existe ou não e se não exibe um echo pra mim informando que não existe. Porém ele não executa esse shellscript existe alguma maneira para que eu contorne esse problema.

Sistema Operacional usado : **Windows Home Single**

Emulado com o **Docker ToolBox**

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM centos
USER root
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY . /home/app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN sh install.sh
```

*install.sh*

```
if [ -f "data/global/workspaces.json" ]; then
    sed -i 's/"tp": \[\]/"tp": ["master"]/g' data/global/workspaces.json
else 
    echo "Erro: File ./data/global/workspaces.json not found!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente dar permissão de execução do arquivo:

```
FROM centos
USER root
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY .* /home/app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN chmod +x install.sh  <<<<<<=
RUN sh install.sh
```

Comment: Olá Ronald, na verdade já tentei aplicar chmod 777 para dar permissão porém eu acredito que seje algum problema com o Docker Tools no Windows pois estou executando ele no notebook da empresa e ele sempre exibi um erro de sintax onde falta o fechar o `fi` e o sistema é Windows Home Single, porém ao executar isso numa VM (com Ubuntu) ele não exibe erro nenhum, gostaria de saber se á alguma maneira para contornar esse problema no meu notebook da empresa alguma permissão no Tools, problema no bash ou algo similar .

Comment: Cara... eu não vejo sentido, pois o docker toolbox também é uma vm, só que no caso, se você está tentando montar de um diretorio do windows, vc está fazendo errado pois não há conversão de CRLF para LF.

Comment: Eu sugiro você subir dois containers no toolbox, como:
Um container servidor samba, no qual vc expõe a porta dele e então fica disponivel para a sua máquina windows, se não me engano no ip 192.168.99.100 e assim vc montar esse servidor smb no seu windows, e assim trabalhar com seus artefatos no VSCODE.
O outro container, seria um ambiente de desenvolvimento onde vc colocaria suas coisas, no qual, o volume que é montado no servidor samba é montado neste container em /root

Comment: Ronald provavelmente é com o CRLF para LF mesmo como você tinha comentado, como eu estou clonando os arquivos do git e pedindo para o docker copiar da minha maquina para a imagem do dockerfile onde ele tem problemas ao executar o shellscript porém ao criar um .sh dentro da imagem o mesmo vem a funcionar .
Bom outra alternativa foi de somente baixar o dockerfile e inserir a instalação do git e clonar ele dentro do build da imagem no docker